# how to put two or more line from a text file to a variable using php?

Tags: php

one line in a variable is good but how assign in a variable multiple lines in text file?

--sample text file----

```
jeff              ->line0
35                ->line1
123456            ->line2
"this is          ->line3
the message       ->line4
from you"         ->line5
```

How to assign the line 3,4 and 5 to a single variable?

code:

```
<?php

    $lines = file('sample.txt');
    $vara= $lines[0];
    $varb= $lines[1];
    $varc= $lines[2];

   ?>
```

Comment: is it possible to do it in a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like this:

```
 //concatenate the last 3 lines and remove the break lines
 $result=preg_replace('/\s{2,}/', ' ', $lines[3].$lines[4].$lines[5]);
 print $result;
```

#### Output:

```
"this is the message from you"
```

#### Update:

Loop all lines in the file:

```
    $lines = file('sample.txt');
    $result="";
   if (array_key_exists(3,$lines)) {
    //assuming that always the comment begins from line 3
    for($i=3; $i<count($lines);$i++){
      $result .=preg_replace('/\s{2,}/', ' ', $lines[$i]);
    }
    }
    print $result;
```

Comment: is it possible to do it in a loop?

Comment: is there  a way to read line 3 or up depends if the line from 3 to up is not empty... because the line 3 is a message... what if the message is long that compose of hundred lines...

Comment: see update :setting $i to 3 will do the job: this means starting from the line 3 till the end of the text file get the message and remove the extra blanc spaces.

Comment: you can add if (array_key_exists(3,$lines)) {//the rest of the code}to check if the line 3 exist

Answer (score 1):

You can just assign multiple lines to a single variable using a dot `.`

```
<?php

$lines = file('sample.txt');
$a= $lines[0];
$b= $lines[1];
$c= $lines[2];
$d= $lines[3] . $lines[4] . $lines[5];

echo $a . "<br>";
echo $b . "<br>";
echo $c . "<br>";
echo $d . "<br>";


?>
```

output:

```
jeff
35
123456
"this is the message from you"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very hard to understand for me and having errors.

```
$var a= $lines[0];
^================> //using $ before var is wrong you should use following
var $a= $lines[0];
```

As i can understand you can do following:

```
<?php

    $lines = file('sample.txt');
    var $a= $lines[0];
        $a += $lines[1];
        $a += $lines[2];

?>
```